# mp3 player extension for Joomla 1.0.x

Tags: joomla

I am after any mp3 player extension for Joomla 1.0.x

I am not a Joomla guy so it would be great if there is also any nice piece of documentation how to make it work.

My friend's site is in Joomla 1.0.x and I cannot update to the latest Joomla version.

Tried to google it but it's hard to find anything for 1.0 these days...

Answer (score 1):

I don't use Joomla so I just resorted to Google: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/multimedia/multimedia-display/4596

Comment: I have installed this one but I cannot make it work :-(

Comment: How come you haven't upgraded to the newest version of joomla?

Comment: It's not my web site. I am only trying to help with the mp3 player. And and I found nice player I realized that it is only for Joomla 1.5 ... It is production site and I am not confident to upgrade it. I have no administration experience with Joomla.